# At which points is function invertible?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, matrices

Determine on which points is mapping local invertible?

$f: \mathbb R ^{2}\mapsto \mathbb R ^{2}$

$\left(x,y\right)\mapsto\left(x^{2}-4y^{2}+x, -xy+3y  \right)  $

I calculated Jacobian matrix and then I tried to calculated determinante of Jacobian matrix to get some points. But I have two unknowns. Can someone help me with this?

$D=0$

$-2x^{2}+5x-8y^{2}+3 =0   $

Comment: $2x^2 - 5x + 8y^2 - 3 = (\sqrt 2 x - \frac 5 4 \sqrt 2)^2 + 8y^2 - \frac{25}{8} - 3 = 0$, that's an equation of a circle.

Comment: Ok. But what that tells me about points? I dont understand.

Comment: An ellipsis, indeed.

Comment: @AnaMatijanovic: each point of the ellipsis is a point where the Jacobian determinant is zero.

Comment: So I cant write any specific points? I am exercising math with computer tests, so I thought I should get some specific points?